# How to apply css to div which has no class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating some design part in HTML. I have two div. Both div element are generating through java script. First div has a class and second div has no any class or id. I want to apply style to second div.

```
<div class="class_name"></div>
<div style="display:block;"></div>
```

After applying style the second div style will be **style="display:none;"**

Please suggest.

Comment: while adding div via javascript, add style to it at the same time

Comment: What's the class name of first div?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't add a class? Also, there are many different selectors in css for selecting elements in many different ways, it depends on the structure of your HTML, so that would be useful to know.

Comment: Alter your Javascript to add a class to the second div? Any other solution is pretty much a needless ballache.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two divs..? Post the corresponding html structure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have CSS only solution for this, there is no need to have a javscript for this you can try [adjacent siblings selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) of CSS:

To target very next div you need this:

```
.FirstClassName + div{
  /*your style goes here */
}
```

To target all divs in a parent after a given class name:

```
.FirstClassName ~ div{
  /*your style goes here */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gXLC/6/)

Comment: "To target all divs after class occurrence:" ..?

Comment: @TJ It means all divs in a single parent after a given class name!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not` selector for the second `div`:

```
div:not([class="classname_of_the_first_div_here"]){}
```

or even simpler :

```
div:not(.classname_of_the_first_div_here)
```

Comment: why not just `div:not(.class_of_first)` ?

Comment: @Patsy Issa : just to make it demonstrative.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there were no other `div` before the two `div` elements were created:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

use style attribute in the second div

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it has only two div's then use the last-child property.

```
yourparent div:last-child
{
your style
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically have three options (maybe more, but then we need some code).

First one, use the element selector. **but that means you're styling all elements of the same type on the page**

```
div { background: red; }
```

Second option, style all divs that have no class attribute:

```
div:not([class]) { background: green; }
```

and last but not least, style a div that is a child of another element. If your document structure is build up properly this is most probably the way to go.

```
div.parent > div { background: blue; }
```

Checkout the [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fcw5D/)